# Electron menu keeps saying that ipc is not defined when clicked even when the ipc is assigned globally in main

Tags: javascript, menu, electron, ipc

in my menu.js under "label:'Database'", the click event returns an error: ipc is not defined. I thought that if this is part of the main.js files and that if I already have a const declared as ipc globally then shouldn't JS look scopes above and find ipc?

main.js:

```js
const electron = require('electron'),
{app, Menu} = require('electron'),      
Window = electron.BrowserWindow,      
path = require('path'),   
url = require('url'),      
ipc = require('electron').ipcMain,   // COMMUNICATIONS MODULE BETWEEN MAIN/RENDERER      
template = require('./menu.js');      

// let mainWindow
app.on('ready', () => {    
  // LOADS THE DEFAULT WINDOW
  let first_Window = new Window({width:800, height:600, frame:false}) 
  first_Window.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:'
  }))    
  const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template)
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)       
})
```

Menu.js:

```js
module.exports = [ 
  {
    label: 'stuff',
    submenu: [
      {role: 'undo'},
      {role: 'redo'},
      {type: 'separator'},
      {role: 'cut'},
      {role: 'copy'},
      {role: 'paste'},
      {role: 'pasteandmatchstyle'},
      {role: 'delete'},
      {role: 'selectall'}
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'Database',
    click() {
       ipc.send('open_database', '')
    }
  },
  {
    label: 'View',
    submenu: [
      {role: 'reload'},
      {role: 'forcereload'},
      {role: 'toggledevtools'},
      {type: 'separator'},
      {role: 'resetzoom'},
      {role: 'zoomin'},
      {role: 'zoomout'},
      {type: 'separator'},
      {role: 'togglefullscreen'}
    ]
  },
  {
    role: 'window',
    submenu: [
      {role: 'minimize'},
      {role: 'close'}
    ]
  },
  {
    role: 'help',
    submenu: [
      {
        label: 'Learn More',
        click () { require('electron').shell.openExternal('https://electron.atom.io') }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Note: My menu shows up just fine. The error only occurs if I click on database.

Comment: what do you want to do with `ipc` there? your menu.js and main.js are both running in main process.
and 
_"if I already have a const declared as ipc globally then shouldn't JS look scopes above and find ipc?"_ **No**. It should not.

Comment: Oh right, because it's the same process, somehow i forgot that menu.js isn't part of the rendering process lol. Although I tried the method suggest below, but its giving me an error in syntax on import {BrowserWindow} from 'electron;  I just want to use the menu click to open a new browser window.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `ipc` in the menu.js for this. It's already running the same process. I would suggest using `webcontents` instead.

In your `menu.js` import BrowserWindow and change the `click` function under `Database`

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

label: 'Database',
click: () => {
  const focusedWindow = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
  focusedWindow.webContents.send('open-database');
}
```

Then in your `main.js` add a listener for the `database` message and open a new `BrowserWindow`

```
ipcMain.on('open-database', () => {
  // open new BrowserWindow

});
```

Comment: Um so it gives me an error: uncaught exception menu.js:1 (function(exports,require,module,_filename,_dirname,process,global,Buffer){ return function(exports,require,module,_filename,_dirname) { import { BrowserWindow } from 'electron';   SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Comment: @Lifeislifebutwhatiswhat Sorry I was using es6 import syntax. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Menu` is a main process class, you don't have to use ipc communication for doing things like opening a new `BrowserWindow` (what you apparently want).

```js
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

module.exports = [
  {
    label: 'Database',
    click (menuItem, browserWindow, event) {
      let win = new BrowserWindow()
      win.loadURL('https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/menu-item/')
    }
  }
]
```

should be enough in your template for this.

Note that if you plan to communicate with your window's renderer process, `click` callback comes with `browserWindow` argument giving you access to the window containing the menu item (see `click` property of [`MenuItem`](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/menu-item/#new-menuitemoptions) in documentation). You can then `executeJavascript` or `send` ipc message to renderer process using this argument.

*Also note, that despite the fact that `BrowserWindow` (or `ipc` or whatever) is already defined in an other file which requires this template, you have to define it again. Require/import/include chains doesn't work in two direction*